# Elixir/Erlang: Fast lookup with static table

Tags: erlang, elixir, lookup-tables

In my application I need to convert integer to some term; for example:

```
1 → :red
2 → :green
3 → :blue
```

The table is static, it is known during compilation time and its indices range from <1, n>. There is around 60 of them.

In which way should the table be represented, so the lookup is the fastest? Dict, HashDict, tuple (with kernel.elem()), ets, function with pattern matching...?

Comment: The HTTP server cowboy uses pattern matching to map HTTP status codes to status texts: [cowboy_req.erl](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/blob/master/src/cowboy_req.erl#L1116)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Julius Beckmann suggested in this case functions with pattern matching should be sufficient as they are according to my measurements over 5 times faster than accessing a map.

Below you can find an implementation of what you are looking for (benchmark code included at the bottom):

```
defmodule TermLookUpByInteger do
  @term_by_integer %{
    1 => :aa, 11 => :ba, 21 => :ca, 31 => :da, 41 => :ea, 51 => :fa, 61 => :ga,
    2 => :ab, 12 => :bb, 22 => :cb, 32 => :db, 42 => :eb, 52 => :fb, 62 => :gb,
    3 => :ac, 13 => :bc, 23 => :cc, 33 => :dc, 43 => :ec, 53 => :fc, 63 => :gc,
    4 => :ad, 14 => :bd, 24 => :cd, 34 => :dd, 44 => :ed, 54 => :fd, 64 => :gd,
    5 => :ae, 15 => :be, 25 => :ce, 35 => :de, 45 => :ee, 55 => :fe, 65 => :ge,
    6 => :af, 16 => :bf, 26 => :cf, 36 => :df, 46 => :ef, 56 => :ff, 66 => :gf,
    7 => :ag, 17 => :bg, 27 => :cg, 37 => :dg, 47 => :eg, 57 => :fg, 67 => :gg,
    8 => :ah, 18 => :bh, 28 => :ch, 38 => :dh, 48 => :eh, 58 => :fh, 68 => :gh,
    9 => :ai, 19 => :bi, 29 => :ci, 39 => :di, 49 => :ei, 59 => :fi, 69 => :gi,
    0 => :aj, 10 => :bj, 20 => :cj, 30 => :dj, 40 => :ej, 50 => :fj, 60 => :gj,
  }

  @doc """
    iex> TermLookUpByInteger.lookup_pmf(2)
    :ab
  """
  def lookup_pmf(int), do: do_lookup(int)

  for {int, term} <- @term_by_integer do
    defp do_lookup(unquote(int)), do: unquote(term)
  end

  @doc """
    iex> TermLookUpByInteger.lookup_m(3)
    :ac
  """
  def lookup_m(int), do: @term_by_integer[int]
end

# Benchmark:

n = 1_000_000
range = 1..(n)
measure = fn fun -> :timer.tc(fn -> for _ <- range, do: fun.() end) end
{time_pmf, _result} = measure.(fn -> TermLookUpByInteger.lookup_pmf(:random.uniform(60)) end)
{time_m, _result}   = measure.(fn -> TermLookUpByInteger.lookup_m(:random.uniform(60)) end)

IO.puts "                      Sample size: #{n}"
IO.puts "Pattern matching functions lookup: #{time_pmf/1000} ms"
IO.puts "                       Map lookup: #{time_m/1000} ms"
IO.puts "              Absolute Difference: #{(time_pmf-time_m)/1000} ms"
IO.puts "              Relative Difference: #{round((time_pmf-time_m)/time_m*100)}%"
IO.puts "                           Faster: x #{Float.round(time_m/time_pmf, 2)} times"
```

Results:

```
                      Sample size: 1000000
Pattern matching functions lookup: 447.6 ms
                       Map lookup: 2423.517 ms
              Absolute Difference: -1975.917 ms
              Relative Difference: -82%
                           Faster: x 5.41 times
```

I hope that will be useful.

Comment: Thank you, this is very thorough!

Comment: What versions of Elixir/Erlang did you test with? I'm asking because maps got a lot faster in Erlang 18/Elixir 1.2 and I'm curious whether that changes the recommendation here. My tests (on a similar bit of code) seem to indicate that it matters, but I didn't benchmark as carefully as you did. For me it seemed that with new versions, runtime performance was the same but compile time was much faster with maps. https://gist.github.com/nathanl/27e19896bba489799804

Answer (score 5):

If the map is completely static and will not change, you can use generated pattern matching. This will be the fastest way to integrate that lookup in your application.

Some example code, reading these mappings from a external file: https://github.com/h4cc/slugger/blob/master/lib/slugger.ex#L69-72
Instead of using a external file, your source map data can be held in a `@attribute`.

Even if new mappings will be needed on runtime, these could be handled with a catchall-pattern match doing a lookup in a HashDict.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I like the idea of catchall-pattern for changes (even though it will not be needed in my case). Do you have any sources to support your statement that this approach will be the fastest?

Comment: @TomášBrukner since this approach is used to handle UTF-8 characters in Elixir, I suppose it should be fast enough for your application. For a real world example, have a look at the implementation of [`String.downcase/1`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/unicode/unicode.ex#L48-L52). It reads all unicode characters from a file during compile time and generates a pattern for each one. Remember that pattern matching is highly optimized in the Erlang VM.

Comment: Here's a discussion on the efficiency of clause selection (pattern matching) in Erlang: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2007-July/027954.html ;; In summary, the compiler will try to build the fastest decision tree it can, but the complexity of clause selection is not guaranteed and is dependent on several factors. For your particular case, it should be more than sufficient, but beware: such lookup functions can become difficult-to-maintain eyesores when they get to be particularly large.

Answer (score 2):

If you rely on fast access from many processes, then [mochiglobal](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb/blob/master/src/mochiglobal.erl) may be the answer. It's tricky constant pool, which keeps keys and values as functions in module. Every time you `put/2` something, module is recompiled (it's slow but doesn't matter in your case). With this approach `value` is not copied into process heap as it is function call. Here is better [explanation](http://prog21.dadgum.com/10.html).